# Query for multiple values at once

Tags: sqlalchemy

In SQL, I can get a set of rows like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id in (2,3,5,7,11);
```

How does the equivalent sqlalchemy query look? `cls.id in [2,3,5,7,11]` evaluates to `False`, so this code:

```py
q = meta.Session.query(cls)
q = q.filter(cls.id in [2,3,5,7,11])
return q.all()
```

fails with an exception:

```
  File "foo.py", line 1234, in findall_by_ids
    q = q.filter(cls.id in [2,3,5,7,11])
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/eggs/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 50, in generate
    fn(self, *args[1:], **kw)
  File "/eggs/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 1177, in filter
    "filter() argument must be of type "
ArgumentError: filter() argument must be of type sqlalchemy.sql.ClauseElement
               or string
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use [in_](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/tutorial.html#common-filter-operators)

```
q.filter(cls.id.in_([2, 3, 5, 7, 11]))
```

Your interpreter said:

```
ArgumentError: filter() argument must be of type sqlalchemy.sql.ClauseElement
               or string
```

Those operators have been overwritten and will return what filter need, you can take a look at `sqlalchemy.sql.operators`. The reason that `cls.id in [2, 3, 5, 7, 1]` doesn't work is because that [`in`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) is the operator of [2, 3, 5, 7, 1], it'll return `True` or `False`.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`in_`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/tutorial.html#common-filter-operators), like this:

```
q = meta.Session.query(cls)
q = q.filter(cls.id.in_([2,3,5,7,11]))
return q.all()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you dont know PK columns best solution is to use `get` but its for one row.

For a non-composite PK

```
pk = model.__mapper__.primary_key[0]
items = model.query.filter(pk.in_(ids)).all()
```